# Validate image for aspect ratio

Tags: drupal-7

I have a requirement where I want to restrict a user to upload profile picture of specific aspect ratio only say square image.
I thought of using module available such as:
1) Manual crop
2) Javascript image crop
but no luck, none working fine.
Then I thought of adding custom validation of forms using hook_form_alter(), adding custom validator name to validate property of form, but I'm stuck how to fetch the uploaded file dimensions so I can check if it meet the requirement of aspect ratio.

Any suggestion of module by which I can achieve this of a feature where user can crop image while uploading or any help in how to move forward to write custom validation, would be really appreciated.

I'm new to Drupal. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Configuration » Media » Image styles you can add a new Image Style and crop the images to your specific aspect ratio.

In Structure » Content types » "Your Content Type" » Manage Display you can set this Style to your Image Field. That way all Images will be croped.